# Modal form does dismiss upon close

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, messagebox

I have a modal form say form1. There is a button, when users click it, another modal form shows up say formchild. If there is any error, I want to dismiss formchild and display a messagebox. 
I use the following code. However, what I see is a messagebox displays on the top of formchild.
How to make formchild disappear/close?  Thanks

```
        formchild.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        formchild.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(error, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put an "If" statement before you call the formchild?

```
//some codes here:
if (!Error)
    formchild.ShowDialog();
else
    Messagebox.Show("Error has occured.");
```

Or if that's not possible, try putting that if statement in formchild.Load.

```
      private void formchild_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       //some codes here:
           if (Error)
           {                        
                Messagebox.Show("Error has occured.");
                this.Close();
           }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. formchild is displayed while a web service call is done asynchronously. formchild will be displayed until the web service call is done. If web service call returns an error, then I need dismiss formchild and displayerror. If not, I simply dismiss formchild and do something else.  That's why I can't do it in formchild_load or before showDialog.  Thanks

Comment: I don't seem to understand your situation.. formchild is shown while web service call is running? then it will be shown again after a web service call is done?

Comment: It is shown when a web service is running and close when web service is done.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is set Visible to false for formchild. Thanks

```
formchild.Visible = false;
formchild.Close();
MessageBox.Show(error, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
```